# Why isn't cv2.waitKey on a callback to reduce performance overhead?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am using eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0) and PyDev 9.0.3. I am running a "standard" motion detect pipeline with python 3.6 and Opencv 3 on windos 10.  I attached a snapshop of pstats from a run of 500 frames.  The algorithm runs the usual mask, gray frame, Gaussian blur, absdiff, dilation and contour detection.  I made sure there was movement in all frames. I save  the movement frames (with moments). Next to file writing with imwrite, cv2.waitKey(1) is the largest consumer of time, to my surprise, slower than running the opencv pipeline (must be good code in opencv). I can't display using cv2.imshow without the cv2.waitKey(1). Is there work to remove this dependency, and, put the keyboard event in a callback?
 ! [image]

Comment: opencv gui is for experimental development, quick tests etc. Use Qt or any other real gui solution. During waitJey, rendering is petformed, which is one of the reasons why it consumes some time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will check out other UI packages.